# webpack.config.js синтаксис

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

встретил такие вот строки, что значит **троеточие**, в данном фрагменте

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ...htmlArray,
]
```

Все работает, все собирается, начал разбирать и уже голову сломал что это может значить.

Answer (score 1):

Это называется `Sperad/Rest оператор`.

Пример с [документации MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(...numbers)
```

С помощью `Spread` оператора можно сделать разделение, к примеру HTMLCollection:

```js
const set = document.querySelectorAll('.item')

console.log('HTMLCollection:', set)
console.log('Separate elements:', ...set)
```

```html
<div class="item">1<div>
<div class="item">2<div>
<div class="item">3<div>
<div class="item">4<div>
<div class="item">5<div>
```

Если говорить про `Rest`, то он наоборот, соединяет элементы, пример:

```js
function nums(...args) {
  console.log(args);
};


nums(1,2,3,4)
```